# Git - remove file extension recursively

Tags: git

I'm trying to remove file extension recursively, but it keeps on failing, whatever I'm trying. Thanks for any idea.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-laptop:~/hh/hh_sdk/src/uboot_hh$ git rm -r --cached \*.o
fatal: pathspec 'src/uboot_hh/*.o' did not match any files
ubuntu@ubuntu-laptop:~/hh/hh_sdk/src/uboot_hh$ sudo git rm -r --cached \*.o
fatal: pathspec 'src/uboot_hh/*.o' did not match any files
ubuntu@ubuntu-laptop:~/hh/hh_sdk/src/uboot_hh$ sudo git rm -r --cached *.o
fatal: pathspec 'src/uboot_hh/*.o' did not match any files
ubuntu@ubuntu-laptop:~/hh/hh_sdk/src/uboot_hh$ sudo find . -name *.o -exec git rm -r --cached {} \;
 fatal: pathspec 'src/uboot_hh/lib_arm/_divsi3.o' did not match any files
fatal: pathspec 'src/uboot_hh/lib_arm/cache.o' did not match any files
fatal: pathspec 'src/uboot_hh/lib_arm/_udivsi3.o' did not match any files
fatal: pathspec 'src/uboot_hh/lib_arm/_umodsi3.o' did not match any files
```

Comment: Are any of your `.o` files actually tracked by Git?

Answer (score 3):

The `find` approach should work well but you need to single-quote the `'*.o'` pattern since the shell would otherwise expand the `*` before passing it to `find`.

Also you need to pass the `--force` option (`-f`) to `git rm` if the file does not exists in the file system anymore:

```
find -name '*.o' -exec git rm -f -r --cached {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it exactly as you wrote, but I still get fatal: pathspec 'src/linux/linux-04.02.00.07/mm/vmalloc.o' did not match any files
fatal: pathspec 'src/linux/linux-04.02.00.07/mm/madvise.o' did not match any files
......
And I still see these files in git gui" as unstanged changes

Comment: What is the output of: `find -name '*.o' -exec bash -c 'file={}; echo "$file"; git rm -f -r --cached "$file";' \;` ?

Comment: hi, it's still the same.

Comment: it appears in "git gui" on unstages changes list, but not when doing in console: git diff -r. What does it mean ?

Comment: @ransh I have to admit that I never experienced this before. Hard to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

It seems your files are **already ignored** that's why git gives the error when you execute the command

```
find -name '*.log' -type f -exec git rm --cached {} \;

### fatal: pathspec './modules/logger/logs/newleaf_2019-08-19.log' did not match any files
```

So please first check is your file is **ignored already** or not you can run this command to test the files if ignored already or not

```
find -name '*.log' -exec git check-ignore --v {} \;

OR TEST SINGLE FILE

git check-ignore --v ./modules/logger/logs/test.log
```

if Files ignore you get will get this output otherwise, it will returns empty.

```
.gitignore:4:logs/      ./modules/logger/logs/test.log
```